# SQL Server collation does not sort the way I want

Tags: sql-server, sorting, collation

I'm working with a small list of european companies, which is supposed to be sorted in a particular order. None of the SQL collations I've tried does the job fully...

**Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS**
Sorts Å, Ä and Ö correctly but thinks that Y and Ü are the same.

**Latin1_General_CI_AS**
Sorts Y and Ü correctly but thinks Å and A are the same, and so on.

What I want is a list sorted like:

- Company AB, Borlänge
- Company AB, Stockholm
- Company AB, Älvsjö (Correct with Swedish, but sorts as "...Alvsjo" in Latin)
- Company OÜ, Otepää (Correct with Latin, but sorts as "Company OY..." in Swedish)
- Company OY, Mikkeli
- Company OY, Saavonlinna

There don't seem to be any particular collation that does the trick. Can I somehow force specific collation/sorting for a specific column? Any other hints to get this right?

Comment: Is your desired sort standard? That is, would they appear in this way in the telephone book?

Comment: At least that´s what I thought, but I'm not sure that's the case. My idea of Accent Sensitive was also that it would include all types of accents, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use a single collation for each operation. If you want to mix cultures, you would have to store a normalised version of the name to use for sorting.

The normalised version for `Company OÜ, Otepää` would be `Company OU, Otepää` so that you could treat `Ü` as if it's not an `Y`.

Comment: Basically I was hoping to solve this issue just by managing the database, since I have no access to the application code. A straight forward solution would be to just use Company OU for display aswell.

Comment: @lovlka: You chould create the normalised value on the fly when you sort them, but that is of course not very efficient.